# How to authenticate AD users for a .Net Web Application

Tags: windows, dns

We have a .Net Web Application, that needs to integrate Active Directory for authentication. What permissions must be enabled from Domain Controller and how can we connect?

Thanks,

Shabin

Now they are accessing with DB user authentication